# Why does System.Data.SqlClient complain about my statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

What I am trying to achieve is the generation and insertion of a unique identifier into each entry I make to the table.

[image]

I have added the default value `(newsequentialid())` to the UserID column, therfore when I execute an INSERT query directly to the database then the result is as expected (the UserID is automaticaly generated and increments each time a new value is added).

However this is not the case when I execute a query through my ASP.NET WebService which provides the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand type clash: int is
>   incompatible with uniqueidentifier

I understand that the error is indicating a data type clash, but I am not intending to populate that coloumn from within my C# code rather it should be added automaticaly?! (no?)

```
DataClassesDataContext dbContext = new DataClassesDataContext();
AddingNewUsers.UserName = UserName; 
AddingNewUsers.UserPass = UserPass; 
AddingNewUsers.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB); 
AddingNewUsers.EmailAddress = Email; 
AddingNewUsers.JoiningDate = DateTime.Today; 
AddingNewUsers.Status = "Active"; 
AddingNewUsers.WalletAmount = 0;     
dbContext.UserTables.InsertOnSubmit(AddingNewUsers);
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: unique Identifier expects a `GUID` you should alter the UserId to be a Int change the Datatype to Int also if you plan to populate that field via C# code then that column should not be an auto increment column

Comment: It might be helpful to use SQL Server Profiler to see exactly what statements are being sent from your app to the database server. Sometimes this can help give you some insight into the nature and source of the problem.

Comment: @MethodMan: post this as an answer as apparently this is a correct answer.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uniqueidentifier` expects a `GUID` you should alter the UserId to be a Int change the Datatype to Int also if you plan to populate that field via C# code then that column should not be an `auto increment column`

Comment: I wouldn't want to populate it from C#, so I set the column to an Identity column and enabled Identity increment, but now it complains that IDENTITY_INSERT should be on, all resources online suggest that I should do that at every insert statement which isnt Ideal, any suggestions?

Comment: according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx I should be able to use it Unique Identifier to each entry (UserID)

Comment: Solved, I had to go into my .dbml class and change the column property to Auto Generated Value = True